# Windows api SIZE_T don't show same value in memory and in console

Tags: c++, windows, iostream

I'm trying to deal with a SIZE_T var in a Windows.h structure but there is a problem with the value returned.

I don't understand why it's different between memory and output.

The less funny it's that i should work in memory with the value that is displayed in console. Then i'm stuck.

#### Introduction

I tryed some tests to see if it's normal.

Code:

```cpp
SIZE_T aaa = 10000;
std::cout << "The aaa value is : " << aaa << std::endl;
```

Output :

```
The aaa value is : 2710
```

I tryed to force cast to see if the value would change in memory

```cpp
int a = (int)aaa;
unsigned int b = (unsigned int)aaa;
long c = (long)aaa;
unsigned long d = (unsigned long)aaa;
```

But still same, the value stay same in memory (10000).

#### The main problem

Code:

```cpp
SIZE_T val;
WindowsFunct(&val); //val get 65536 in memory
std::cout << "The val is : " << val << std::endl;
```

Output :

```
The val is : 10000 //The value that i would deal with in my program
```

Then is their a way to get in memory the value that is displayed?

**Edit:**
The original code:

```cpp
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
LPVOID mainModuleAddr = (LPVOID)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
VirtualQuery(mainModuleAddr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi));
std::cout << "Main module Region Size: " << mbi.RegionSize << std::endl;
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "in memory"? Are you looking at this value in a debugger and seeing a different value than in the console?

Comment: Yes exactly Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 2710 output is because at some point you had fed the std::hex iomanip to cout. 10000 == 0x2710.

If you use the std::dec iomanip it will show as 10000.

```
std::cout << "The aaa value is : " << std::dec << aaa << std::endl;
```